# How to add items of arrays to end of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is `sourceArray` and some `additionalArray`. Need to add items from `additionalArray` to the end of `sourceArray`. And in result `sourceArray` contains all items (no create new array). The problem is items count of `additionalArray` may be thousands.

```js
// example
push([], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]) // [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]
push(['a', 'b'], 'x', ['z', '0']) // ['a', 'b', 'x', 'z', '0']
```

```js
// my solution
function push(sourceArray, ...additionalArray) {
    additionalArray.forEach((array) => {
        array = Array.isArray(array) ? array : [array];
        if (array.length < 1000) {
            sourceArray.push.apply(sourceArray, array);
        } else {
            array.forEach((item) => sourceArray.push(item));
        }
    });
    return sourceArray;
}
```

My question is there more elegant solution for this task?

Comment: Why don't you use the spread operator? `const newArray = [...sourceArray, ...additionalArray]`

Comment: @SajeebAhamed Because I heard about limit of count items

Comment: If you need the original array reference to be unmodified (i.e. no new array) then you can split up your array params into groups before iterating them and pushing into the original array. Basically what's been suggested but using groups to ensure you don't max out the `push` params limit.

Comment: Since you're not creating a new array, is there really any sense in `return`ing `sourceArray`? It's passed by reference and updated.

Comment: @PeterKA sometimes is more convenient. For example, with one line `=>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find using [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) can help you here. If you use that on `additionalArray`, you can then spread `...` those elements into a call to `.push()` as arguments:

```js
const push = (source, ...rest) => {
  source.push(...rest.flat());
  return source;
}

console.log(push([], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])) // [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]
console.log(push(['a', 'b'], 'x', ['z', '0'])) // ['a', 'b', 'x', 'z', '0']
```

This does have a limitation though in that `.push()` can only accept a certain amount of arguments. You might hit the max argument limit and this can throw considering that your `additionalArray` can be large. Using a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop would help with that:

```js
const push = (source, ...rest) => {
  for(const item of rest.flat())
    source.push(item)
  return source;
}

console.log(push([], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])) // [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]
console.log(push(['a', 'b'], 'x', ['z', '0'])) // ['a', 'b', 'x', 'z', '0']
```

Comment: No need of returning `source`.

Comment: @PeterKA yes there isn't a need, but usually, these types of methods return the target (which op has named the source for some reason) for convenience (otherwise my console.logs above wouldn't work), take [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for example or `.sort()`. So just following that behavior. If OP wants something else returned (like the length), then they can do that also

Answer (score 0):

As of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#merging_two_arrays), you can use the array spread syntax:

```
let vegetables = ['parsnip', 'potato']
let moreVegs = ['celery', 'beetroot']

// Merge the second array into the first one
vegetables.push(...moreVegs);

console.log(vegetables)  // ['parsnip', 'potato', 'celery', 'beetroot']
```